# I get strange sizzle/artifacts in my audio when doing differnt FFT approaches

Tags: audio, signal-processing, fft

I am doing filter convolution by using fft (FFTW). I experience something I can not understand.
I have an input x(n) which I want to apply a filter IR  u(n). Both length N. So I zero pad  both e.g. to 2n and  do FFT of both to get X(n) and U(n). if I just do X(n)*U(n) and IFFT I get a signal y(t). If I listen to the signal there is no sizzling, all sounds ok. For speeding up the programm and saving memory I tried to take advantage of symmetrie of U(n) and X(n)and to use only first half of U(n) and X(n) and zero padding the second half. So I did  X(n0...n/2,0,0,0,0,..,N)*U(n0,..,n/2,0,0,0,..,N) and IFFT.
The resulting output sounds not different to the result when multipling full length X*U but there is strange subtile sizzling noise audible laying on the output. Mostley apparent on loud/resonant input signal parts, sounds almost like clipping the stage. I did not change anything in the scaling in both methods so, I don´t understand whats going on. Could someone help me out with an idea?

Is it wrong to just use half of U and X and zero pad the rest , must I use the full length? Or does this change e.g. scaling?

Answer (score 0):

You can not simply set part of your signal spectra to zero. Any real signal (with no imaginary component) has a conjugate complex spectrum. I guess this is the symmetry you are talking about. If you set part of the spectrum to zero your signal in the time domain will be complex and completely different from the original signal you started with.

If you want to speed up your computation reduce the number of your samples you are working with